# How do I start with an empty datatable in shiny that gets populated as I search

Tags: r, shiny, datatables

I love the search functionality in datatables, with its rapid filtering as you type.  However, the 'Search' box above a datatable seems to me to be more of a 'filter' box. Is there a way to start with an empty datatable, that gets populated only as I start typing into the search box?

i.e. in the example below, I want the table to start with one empty row, which changes to three rows if I type an 'A', two rows for 'Al, etc.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
data<-data.frame(firstname=c('Albert','Alan','Annabel','Torsten'),lastname=c('Anderson','Brown','Davies','Ford'))

ui<-fluidPage(dataTableOutput('search_table'))

server<-function(input, output, session){
  output$search_table<- renderDataTable(datatable(data))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```